# Why FullTextSqlQuery doesn't return the same results as web front end searching?

Tags: search, fulltextsqlquery

I'm creating FullTextSqlQuery to find some phases in files content.
I have some test files uploaded on one of SPSite with content that match my query conditions. When I search in web browser, I'm getting my test file on result list.
Somehow my FullTextSqlQuery doesn't return those files as a result. There are some results but should be more.
This is my query string:

`SELECT Title,Path FROM SCOPE() WHERE "scope" = 'MyScope' AND ( 
freetext(DefaultProperties,'"tax recovery"') 
OR freetext(DefaultProperties,'"service fee"') 
OR freetext(DefaultProperties,'"hotel tax"') 
OR ( freetext(DefaultProperties,'"hotel"') AND freetext(DefaultProperties,'"sales tax"') )
OR ( freetext(DefaultProperties,'"hotel"') AND freetext(DefaultProperties,'"excise tax"') ) 
)`


What I'm doing wrong? Hot to force SP to find all files that match query conditions?

Comment: Can you add some tags to indicate what version of SharePoint you are using? 2007 or 2010, Foundation or Server etc. Also, can you explain why you are using a SQL Query instead of plain FQL.

Comment: Hi. I'm using SP 2010 server.

Comment: And what about using FQL rather than SQL. SQL is deprecated in 2010 and removed in 2013.

Comment: That is important information. Thank you. I will user FQL.

Answer (score 0):

The FQL for this would be something like:
"tax recovery" OR "service fee" OR "hotel tax" OR "hotel" AND "sales tax" OR "hotel" AND "excise tax"

If you are performing a GET you can add the "sourceid" parameter to specify the desired Result Source in 2013. In 2010 you can add the "s" parameter to indicate the scope.

Comment: Is that correct syntax?: OR (string("tax recovery", mode="phrase") , string("service fee", mode="phrase") , string("hotel tax", mode="phrase") , AND (string("hotel", mode="phrase"), string("sales tax", mode="phrase")) , AND (string("hotel", mode="phrase"), string("excise tax", mode="phrase")) )

Comment: It's off the top of my head, what does "mode=phrase" gain you? I was just mimicking the initial query.